# Illegal blocking mode exception while attempting to read from socket

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, network-programming, inputstream

I am pretty new to Java and am trying to code a sender-channel-receiver setup, where the channel represents a transmission medium and introduces errors to the packets. So the channel is connected to the sender and the receiver using server socket channels. 
Most of it is fine, but when I attempt to read the object `Packet` within the channel, it throws `IllegalBlockingModeException`. The sender throws what seems to be a corresponding IO exception, "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". The code in the `Channel` program is as follows (some parts excluded for simplicity):

```
Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();
while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
    SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();
    keyIterator.remove();
    if (key.isAcceptable()) {
        SocketChannel sc = ((ServerSocketChannel) key.channel()).accept();
        sc.configureBlocking(false);
        sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }
    if (key.isReadable()) {
        SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        sc.configureBlocking(false);
        Packet packet = readPacket(sc);
        sc.close();
        // do things with the packet...
```

where `readPacket` is defined as follows:

```
private static Packet readPacket(SocketChannel sc) throws IOException, 
ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream in = new 
    ObjectInputStream(sc.socket().getInputStream());
    Packet packet = (Packet) in.readObject();
    return packet;
}
```

is someone able to please explain what is throwing the exception and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

Streams are blocking. You cannot use them in non-blocking mode. See the Javadoc.

Comment: Indeed I have seen that in the Javadoc. So what I am asking for is how to rectify this? How can I read the socket if not with streams?

Comment: You *can* read it with streams, but not in non-blocking mode. Serialization and NIO are a very poor fit. Decide. One or the other.